# How to include webrtc adapter js into Angular5 app

Tags: angular, typescript, webrtc, angular5

I need to include webrtc-adapter to my Angular 5 app.

What I need to do besides: `npm install webrtc-adapter` ?

Do I need to make any additional imports?

Comment: here is git library you can follow these steps https://github.com/webrtc/adapter

Answer (score 5):

As you said you have to install int via **npm** `npm install webrtc-adapter`, then you need to include it in your `index.js` (or other main entry file) simply by doing:

```
import "webrtc-adapter";
```

at the top of it.

If you are using **webpack** instead of importing it you could add this to your **webpack** config as follow:

```
  entry: {
    application: "src/index",
    vendor: [
      "webrtc-adapter"
    ]
  },
```

Here are some examples how I am doing it in my projects:

- [import directly in main entry file](https://github.com/vardius/peer-cdn/blob/master/src/index.js)
- [using webpack](https://github.com/vardius/webrtc-chat/blob/master/webpack/webpack.config.production.js)

For an easy abstraction layer of **WebRTC** I recommend using [peer-data](https://github.com/vardius/peer-data)

Answer (score 5):

Include `import 'webrtc-adapter';` in every component or service that uses WebRTC.

Also you need to import two zone.js patches:

```
// rtc peer connection patch
import 'zone.js/dist/webapis-rtc-peer-connection';
// getUserMedia patch
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-patch-user-media';
```

If you are using `angular-cli` you should add these lines in `polyfills.ts` after `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';` that's already in this file.